# How to fix crash 'Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

I'm facing a crash. There's no accurate code show me which line crashed.

I have used a webview in my app. But i'm not sure why it crash.

```
0   CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw
2   CoreFoundation  _CFArgv
3       CoreFoundation  -[__NSPlaceholderSet initWithObjects:count:]
4   CoreFoundation  -[__NSSetM copyWithZone:]
5   UIKitCore   -[UIView _dispatchTintColorVisitorWithReasons:]
6   UIKitCore   -[UIView setTintAdjustmentMode:]
7   UIKitCore   -[_UIButtonBarButtonVisualProviderIOS updateButton:forEnabledState:]
8   UIKitCore   -[_UIButtonBarButton setEnabled:]
9   UIKitCore   -[UIPrintPanelTableViewController setShowContactingPrinter:]
10  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_call_block_and_release
11  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_client_callout
12  libdispatch.dylib   _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
13  CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
14  CoreFoundation  
__CFRunLoopRun
15  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
16  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
17      UIKitCore   UIApplicationMain
18  ChopeDashboard  main.m line 14 main + 14
19  libdyld.dylib   start
```

Is there some faced the same problem, and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-trick/)?

Comment: Maybe that argument not valid. Can you check that

Comment: I found crash log on fabric. and I can't reproduce the crash. So I can't debug on Xcode.

Comment: Well. Read the stack trace carefully. There is a dispatch callback called (you most probably used `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ()^{})` somewhere). It looks like a printing controller is displayed. It's almost impossible to exactly tell without some code. Maybe I could give you a hint to where in your code that might happen.

Comment: Also check how common this issue is and check the system versions. If it's just one single crash per thousand users I'd happily ignore it...

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert Thanks. Yes, i used `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ()^{})`. and reload a tableview. It's about Star Printer.
It really just happend once.

Comment: Perfect. Check that callback if you call `setEnabled:` in there and if you really pass a bool value in any circumstance. Maybe you pass an object which you expect to be nil, which would evaluate to `NO`. That could cause issues down the line.